Migration to new MarkDown engine (CommonMark)
Our site is scheduled to migrate to the new MarkDown handling on the 17th of June, 2020 as explained in this meta.SE post. If you have any issues with the handling of markdown then please let us know.
The main difference is that code blocks will have to use the new fencing format (which you will probably quickly get used to, if you haven't already). Furthermore, lists and such must have correct spacing if you want to have separate paragraphs included like this:

Something
Something part of something, with correct spacing up front.

The $\TeX$ site is already ported over, so I don't expect any issues in that regard. All other features should keep working as expected.
If you experience any issues, please create an answer here. We'll evaluate and possibly (let you) post on meta.SE if necessary.

CommonMark
Migration
Migration seems to have gone smoothly so far. If you have seen many changes to your posts by "Community" then this is because of the new list format conversions (introducing non-visible white space).
Fencing
I was wrong that the fencing is now required; when you read the first link fully you'll find that the fencing is only required when introducing language hints. Language hints for language-specific highlighting are not supported on our site. Currently the button to format code sections hasn't changed either: it will simply use indentation rather than fencing. This seems illogical, at least for StackOverflow, so I would not be surprised if this changes system wide later on.
Editing
Note that the new CommonMark engine may also affect editing speeds. It is expected that it speeds up editing rather than slow it down, but again, if you experience any issues let us know.
Subsections

# header 1 for H1
## header 2 for H2
### header 3 for H3

#### This doesn't work, we're still at 3 levels deep it seems.
Lists
One thing that should be better is lists. For instance, 1) now will be a valid list item. This is the one most new users will try and use, so less formatting for us hopefully. In general, the CommonMark engine will allow a set of additional characters / formatting options so it is easier to guess right - at the expense of requiring better spacing.
Tables
Check here if HTML-based tables are working as expected, currently they seemingly don't (which is kind-of expected, there was a hint that they may work in the future).

This isa table
ofsorts

